# Each Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I do not understand why the error below is thrown. All of my scripts are loaded in the each loop, but I have a hard time seeing the undefined variable.

Error

```
TypeError:
C:\...\views\layout.pug:13
  11|                 include navbarBottom
  12|
> 13|                 each script in scripts
  14|                          script(type='text/javascript', src=script)
  15|
  16|

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

register.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render(
    'register', {
      user: User.build(), 
      title: "Register",
      scripts: [
        '/javascripts/plugins/jquery.min.js',
        '/javascripts/plugins/bootstrap.min.js',
        '/javascripts/plugins/bootstrap-multiselect.js',
        '/javascripts/plugins/jquery-intlTelInput.js',
        '/javascripts/plugins/jquery-intlTelInputUtils.js',
        '/javascripts/register.js',
      ]
    }
  );
});
```

register.pug

```
extends layout

block content

    #register-page.main.container...
```

layout.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title #{title}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    include navbarTop

    block content

    include navbarBottom

    each script in scripts
      script(type='text/javascript', src=script)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the right `render` call ? It doesn't refer to the layout.pug file. Is it included somewhere ?

Comment: It is referring to the register.pug file which extends the layout.pug, do you think that is the issue?

Comment: If i was you, I would hard-code the script tags in `block scripts` in register.pug and added `block scripts` placeholder to layout.pug

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)